# PostgreSQL aggregate over json arrays

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

I have seen a lot of references to using json_array_elements on extracting the elements of a JSON array. However, this appears to only work on exactly 1 array. If I use this in a generic query, I get the error

`ERROR:  cannot call json_array_elements on a scalar`

Given something like this:

| orders |
| --- |
| { "order_id":"2", "items": [{"name": "apple","price": 1.10}]} |
| { "order_id": "3","items": [{"name": "apple","price": 1.10},{"name": "banana","price": 0.99}]} |

I would like to extract

| item | count |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 2 |
| banana | 1 |

Or

| item | total_value_sold |
| --- | --- |
| apple | 2.20 |
| banana | 0.99 |

Is it possible to aggregate over json arrays like this using json_array_elements?

Comment: "*this appears to only work on exactly 1 array. If I use this in a generic query*" - not sure what you mean by that. Can you show us the code that you used, the one that caused the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function for `orders->'items'` to flatten the data:

```sql
select elem->>'name' as name, (elem->>'price')::numeric as price
from my_table
cross join jsonb_array_elements(orders->'items') as elem;
```

It is easy to get the aggregates you want from the flattened data:

```sql
select name, count(*), sum(price) as total_value_sold
from (
    select elem->>'name' as name, (elem->>'price')::numeric as price
    from my_table
    cross join jsonb_array_elements(orders->'items') as elem
    ) s
group by name;
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b0fe1bbc9beccf327406e953d356afec)

Comment: When I run your fiddle, it works fine - but when I swap out WITH ( VALUES ...), with WITH (SELECT * FROM my_local_table), it throws the same error

Comment: How are you calling the table name like that? orders->'items' doesn't really make sense to me since it is not a column name. I am trying it on my local table using your syntax (without the WITH from the fiddle) and it says ERROR:  column "orders" does not exist

Comment: The `orders` in my query is the column name. Replace it with the actual jsonb column name that you forgot to include in the question.

Comment: Right, sorry, the issue ended up actually being that there were null valued arrays in the data. Your answer worked, key was just to also add WHERE orders->>items IS NOT NULL